# Using FFT to calculate Convolutions -- Why it would be faster

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, convolution, computational-mathematics, roots-of-unity

In this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuXjwB4LzSA) it states you can use polynomial multiplication to find the convolution. The box method is metaphorical to convolution for multiplying the coefficients of the polynomial. So what can be done is you can take the two input lists and pretend they are the coefficients of polynomials. Then you can input arbitrary x-values into those polynomials and multiply the output to get a product. Then once you have enough points($N$ of them), you can solve for the coefficients. The big-O notation for this is $N^2$, because you have $N$ required outputs and $N$ terms in each product.

The video states that Fast Fourier Transform(FFT) can be used do this faster. You can take the x-values to be the $N$ $N$th roots of unity. This would allow "redundancy" to occur, which would make the computation faster. FFT would then be used over the set of products to determine the coefficients of the polynomial product and thus the convolution.

But I am confused by this. Sure, the roots of unity would allow for FFT. But what redundancy would the $N$th roots of unity give? The powers of $x$ in the polynomials would be at most $N$, so it wouldn't reset there.

Could someone please explain this to me? Thanks

Comment: If I recall correctly from the video, he did not touch on the fact that FFT requires your data to have length equal to a power of 2. In that case the roots of unity cause the resultant $2^N \times 2^N$ matrix to become a $2\times 2$ block matrix, where the blocks have this redundant structure. So instead of having multiply $2^N \times 2^N$ by a vector, you only have to multiply $2^{N-1}\times 2^{N-1}$ by such. That's the gist, but I'll let someone else explain it better.

Comment: I guess what they call *redundancy* can be explained as follows. Say you want to evaluate a polynomial $P(x)=\sum_j a_jx^j$ at both $x=+1$ and $x=-1$. A useful strategy for doing that is to calculate the sums of even and odd degree coefficients separately. Calculate $E=\sum_j a_{2j}$, and $O=\sum_ja_{2j+1}$, when you get both $P(1)=E+O$ and $P(-1)=E-O$ more or less free of charge (in comparison to calculating
$P(1)=\sum_j a_j$ and $P(-1)=\sum_i(-1)^ja_j$ separately. It is this labor saving way of organizing the calculations.

Comment: (cont'd) When you want to also evaluate $P$ at fourth roots of unity you split the task further. First calculate the sums of the coefficient of $P$ in four parts according to the remainder of the degree modulo four, and then combine them in different ways to get $E$ and $O$ as above, and also what you need to calculate $P(i)$ and $P(-i)$. This can be applied recursively to eighth, sixteenth etc roots of unity.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But for your even-odd example, Yes you can add them up seperately, but you still add $N$ terms overall, right? And sure you do less multiplcation of inputs to sum of coefficients or coefficients, but the time it takes to do multiplication for each term would be independent of $N$, and thus would be ignored in Big-$O$ notation, right?

Comment: If the polynomial has $2k$ terms then both $E$ and $O$ are sums of $k$ numbers, and we need $(k-1)$ additions to get them both. Then we can calculate $P(1)$ and $P(-1)$ in $2(k-1)+2$ additions instead of the brute force $2(2k-1)$, saving a factor of two. But you do need to go down to pairs of terms to see the savings.